# <jee:jndi-lookup default-value and the use of classpath

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jndi, spring-ws, spring-3

I am really stuck on this one... Help! :)

I am using j2ee:jndi lookup for a property file. The following works fine:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="myProps" jndi-name="myProps" resource-ref="true" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

However, I want to handle the case where the jndi lookup fails but will fall back on a default file located in WEB-INF/classes folder. If I use the default-value as below, the webapp throws an exception complaining that it cannot find the file "classpath:myprops.properties"

```
<bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg>
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="myProps" jndi-name="myProps" resource-ref="true"
            default-value="classpath:myprops.properties" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

However, if I hard-code a specific path for default-value, then it works fine, but that is unacceptable as a final solution.

Thus, my issue is how to use "classpath:" so that it gets properly resolved?

This is the overall usage I'm employing:

```
<bean id="authServerProperties"
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="location">
        <bean class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
            <constructor-arg>
                <jee:jndi-lookup id="myProps" jndi-name="myProps" resource-ref="true"
                    default-value="classpath:myprops.properties" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
     </property>
     .....
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let Spring use its built-in `PropertyEditor` support to decide on the type of resource, rather than supplying an explicit `FileSystemResource` bean as this won't work with classpath resources (it needs to be configured with a path on the file system). Instead you should use something like

```
<bean id="authServerProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="location" ref="myProps" />
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup id="myProps" jndi-name="myProps" resource-ref="true"
            default-value="classpath:myprops.properties"/>
```

Here we are setting the location to be a string value and allowing Spring to convert that to the appropriate resource type, so if you have

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>myProps</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>file:///Users/something/myProps.properties</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

in your `web.xml`, it will use a `UrlResource` with the given file URL, otherwise it will create a `ClasspathResource` to look for the file `myprops.properties`.